# ADODB/Excel query error

Tags: sql, excel, adodb

When I try to use ADODB to connect on an Excel DB, it says:

```
you try to execute a query without a specified expression <Destinataire>
```

Here's my code:

```
MyQuery = "Select Destinataire, SUM(" & Entete & ") AS NombreTotal FROM [Feuil1$] " _
                         & "WHERE [DateMad] Between #" _
                         & Format(date_deb, "yyyy/mm/dd") _
                         & "# And #" & Format(date_fin, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#" & Query3 & ""

                    objRecordSet.Open MyQuery, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please, don't build queries concatenating strings!! Use query parameters!!

Comment: Can you check the final value of `MyQuery` after you have built it and post that? Also @Marco, you should give reasons for not using concatenation (eg security/robustness).

Comment: the debug.print give me this:
Select Destinataire, SUM(NbCompteurElec) AS NombreTotal FROM [Feuil1$] WHERE [DateMad] Between #2012/10/22# And #2012/10/26# And [Destinataire] = 'REL12'

Comment: @bendataclear: I should give a reason? Because it's definitely wrong! Because it's evil!! Because you can have serious problems with strings, dates and floats/doubles with localization! Because you cannot maintain queries written in this way!! Some more?

Comment: thx for the input Macro, i appreciat it trust me, i listen on every criticism as i'm really new to programming languages
how can i format the query so it will be correct ?

Comment: Sorry if it sounded like I was dis-agreeing @Marco, I do agree with you, they should not be used but it's important to explain the reasons.

Comment: Hi Phaonis: you could try (in pseudo-code) `var q = new Query("Select Destinataire, SUM(" & Entete & ") AS NombreTotal FROM [Feuil1$] WHERE [DateMad] BETWEEN @dt1 AND @dt2"); q.Parameters.AddWithValue("dt1", date_deb); q.Parameters.AddWithValue("dt2", date_fin);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `group by`

The query should look like this

```
Select Destinataire, SUM(NbCompteurElec) AS NombreTotal FROM [Feuil1$] 
WHERE [DateMad] Between #2012/10/22# And #2012/10/26# And [Destinataire] = 'REL12'
Group By Destinataire
```

In your code it should be like this

```
MyQuery = "Select Destinataire, SUM(" & Entete & ") AS NombreTotal FROM [Feuil1$] " _
                         & "WHERE [DateMad] Between #" _
                         & Format(date_deb, "yyyy/mm/dd") _
                         & "# And #" & Format(date_fin, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#" & Query3 & " Group By Destinataire"
```

[Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) a tuto about the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Glad to help ;) And welcome on Stack Overflow, you can accept an answer clicking on the check beside it

Comment: Might also need to add an alias to the table `Select Tbl.Destinataire FROM [Feuili$] Tbl` as he's querying an Excel sheet, I've had problems without aliases when doing this.